# Delegate Subtractive Assignment

Tags: c#, delegates

In C#, delegate behave more like a list of function pointers, so that we can call a list of methods with the same method signature via a delegate.

After the initial assignment, we can add or subtract methods from a delegate using += (additive assignment) and -= (subtractive assignment).

Say, I have two methods.

```
public static void Method1(string message){
  // ...
}

public static void Method2(string message){
  // ...
}
```

Now, I declare a delegate type,

```
public delegate void Del(string message);
```

If I want to execute Method1, Method2 and again Method1 in order, I can create a delegate like this.

```
Del delList = Method1;
delList += Method2;
delList += Method1;
```

Then, later in the program, If I remove Method1 from it, which occurrence of Method1 is removed? Is there any rule governing that?

I believe that the better and more readable way is to create a new delegate and add methods you want excute in order, instead of changing an existing one. I'm just curious about how `-=` operator is implemented for C# delegates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the matching performed by `-=` doesn't remove the one you wanted, you can call `GetInvocationList()`, manipulate it how you want, and make a new delegate.

However, that's only possible when you have access to the delegate.  For fields, which only have `operator+=` and `operator-=` (subscribe and unsubscribe) behaviors, you'd best avoid duplicates if you care about the order of the calls.

Actually, it would probably be best to avoid duplicates altogether.

To answer the question about the specific behavior (though I still maintain that relying on it is far too confusing), `operator-=` uses [`Delegate.Remove`, which is documented as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.remove.aspx):

> Removes the last occurrence of the invocation list of a delegate from the invocation list of another delegate.

(The documentation for the Delegate class itself says "Managed languages use the `Combine` and `Remove` methods to implement delegate operations. Examples include the `AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler` statements in Visual Basic and the `+=` and `-=` operators on delegate types in C#.")